# Weird time calculation in mysql when adding / subtracting months

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to perform some time calculations (timestampadd, timestampdiff) on a query but I'm stuck with an unexpected behavior.

I executed in mysql this query:

```
select timestampdiff(MONTH, timestampadd(MONTH, 1, '2017-01-30'),'2017-01-30')
```

Using logic is adding to 2017-01-30 one month, then it requests the difference in months between this date and again 2017-01-30.

I'm expecting the result to be trivial and equal to 1 but instead the previous query evaluates to 0.

This screws my calculations.

Why is that?

Comment: Could this: `select MONTH(timestampadd(MONTH, 1, '2017-01-30')) - MONTH('2017-01-30')` be a solution to this issue? This only looks at the month number (ex: feb = 2) and subtracts the two. Now, this might be an issue for you if you are calculating Jan 31 and Feb 1 because it's only one day but this will return `1` month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straight forward,
you are adding 1 month in january 30 which will be feb 28 as in 2017

now the difference between jan30 and feb28 is only 29 days which is less than a month value.  ( 30 days )

Therefore its 0

for accuracy, you need to handle february with care .

Comment: But what is a month value for mysql then? 30 days or 31 days?

Comment: it is 30 days .

Comment: So adding months the month length is variable and can be less than 30 days (Jan 30th to Feb 28th is 28 days) but subtracting is 30 days? That seems really odd to me.

I'll mark the answer as accepted, but I'd like to really understand why the behavior is not symmetric here.

Comment: Yes, infact it is odd !!

Comment: MySQL returns the correct answer for ```SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, 1, '2017-01-30');``` it returns ```2017-02-28``` So then why MySQL Can't calculate this above issue?

Comment: @Dhanushkasasanka Issue is with timestampdiff which takes Month equals to 30 .. so in that case it doesnt completes to be one complete month .

Comment: yes, I know that but why that function ```timestampdiff()``` calculation can't do that ? is that an issue? need to call MySQL Team. :-( :-)

Comment: Nope, its default behaviour. Possible reason could be the difference which is a millisecond value isn't having info of the month .